# play music infinitely until a button is clicked

Tags: android, playback, infinite, interruption

I'm just trying to play music continuously in an infinite loop until a button is clicked.it works fine but,say for eg: my sound file is 5 sec. after every 5 sec there is a pause and the music plays again.Is there anyway to prevent that and play the music without interruption?
I have used **Setlooping(true)** for that infinite loop.

Comment: find some mechanism to cross fade so as to remove the gap between the file replay.

Comment: what about if you lower the bit rate of your music file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your music file likely contains a short pause at the end (or the beginning). You will need to edit this file in a sound editor to make it more suitable for continuous playback.

**EDIT**

To be clear, are you looking to loop *one specific* sound file, or *any* sound file in general?